# Do my eyes deceive me, or is this the basis for the train station in Vigrid (from Bayonetta)?

Tags: video-games, real-location, bayonetta

Today I came across an image of the train station in Antwerp, Belgium.

[image: Antwerp train station, stairs]

I then looked for a zoomed-out photo.

[image: Antwerp train station]

Both very strongly remind me of the one in Vigrid visited by Bayonetta in [the game of the same name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayonetta), as seen in the footage below (at about two and a half minutes in).

Is there any evidence (developer comments/credits) that the one in the game is inspired by a real-world train station, particularly the one in Antwerp?

Comment: This would probably be better asked on [Gaming.SE](//gaming.stackexchange.com)

Comment: @Machavity I did ask there originally. The question got downvoted because questions about "developer intent" are off-topic, so I deleted it.

Comment: The footage looks like any number of (older) European train stations; given that the game seems to take place in an alt-Europe, this shouldn't be considered surprising. I'm not sure that I'd place it as being _specifically_ Antwerpen/Anvers.

Comment: For what it's worth, Grand Central Terminal in New York was deliberately modelled after European train stations, and contains architectural elements that also appear in your pictures of Antwerpen/Anvers above. See some of the pictures at [the terminal's website](https://www.grandcentralterminal.com/what-to-see/).